# Pipenv issue: AttributeError: module 'pipenv.core' has no attribute 'project'

Tags: python, wsgi, pipenv, python-venv

I'm trying to pip install some dependencies into my virtual environment for a flask wsgi server with pipenv and I am met with his error:

[Actual console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2XCL.png)

```
(code-S7821ldY) sentry@sentry:/var/www/code$ sudo pipenv install
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
3/dist-packages/pipenv/resolver.py", line 52, in main
    project = pipenv.core.project
AttributeError: module 'pipenv.core' has no attribute 'project'
```

This all began from trying to install opencv into a python 3.8 virtual environment. I can't seem to find much for this error online, any sort of help would be very much appreciated.

This error also occurs when using pipenv lock, I can still access the shell of the environment regardless of this error. Not sure if this info is helpful but thought I would add it.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Tom Greenwood uninstalling pipenv installed by pip worked for me:

```
pip uninstall pipenv
```

I also had installed pipenv using `sudo apt install pipenv`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and solved it by removing the pipenv version that I had installed with pip (pipenv-2022.1.8). I had also installed pipenv (11.9.0-1) via apt, so it must either be a bug in pipenv-2022.1.8 or a clash caused by having multiple pipenvs installed.

Not a very complete answer I'm afraid but hopefully it might help.